# MyPy Type Check Error: No attribute found in Base class for subclass methods

Tags: python, inheritance, casting, mypy, python-typing

I'm facing an issue with MyPy type checking, and I would appreciate some guidance on resolving it. I have a base class Base and two subclasses Sub1 and Sub2. Each subclass has its own methods (b and c, respectively).

```
class Base:
    def a(self) -> None:
        print("a")

class Sub1(Base):
    def b(self) -> None:
        print("b")

class Sub2(Base):
    def c(self) -> None:
        print("c")
```

I also have a function check that takes an object of type Base and performs different actions based on whether it's an instance of Sub1 or Sub2:

```
def check(obj: Base) -> None:
    obj.a()
    if isinstance(obj, Sub1):
        obj.b()
    elif isinstance(obj, Sub2):
        obj.c()
```

However, when I run MyPy, I get the following error: ***"Base" has no attribute "b" [attr-defined]. Errors were detected by MyPy (exit code 1).***

I understand that MyPy is not aware of the subclass-specific methods, and I'm currently using ***cast*** to work around this issue. Is there a better way to handle this without explicit casting? I've considered using ***Union*** types, but I'm not sure if that's the best approach as there will be additional classes added as sub class and also this attribute will be used in many functions.

Considering the larger use case I have just given an example on the approach but i will be using it many places, Any suggestions on how to structure the types or refactor the code to make MyPy happy would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are your configurations? I [can't replicate](https://mypy-play.net/?flags=strict&mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=91db3387e4d5ba1c5b46f6eda8e9b21b) using `--strict`.

Comment: All these classes are present in different files and check() function is in separate package.

Comment: I'm afraid that is not enough. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Where you able to solve this?

Comment: I landed creating a abstract class where i am adding all the member functions for for mypy checks